# object() takes no paramets but no object() in code

Tags: python

I'm STILL trying to create a code for an assignment but have come across a problem where idle tells me that object() takes no parameters, but in the code there is no object() at all.

```
_world = {}
starting_position = (0, 0)

def load_tiles():
    """Parses file describing the world space in the _world object"""
    with open( "map.txt", 'r') as f:
        rows = f.readlines()
    x_max = len(rows[0].split('\t')) # believes all rows contains same amount of tabs
    for y in range(len(rows)):
        cols = rows[y].split('\t')
        for x in range(x_max):
            tile_name = cols[x].replace('\n', '')
            if tile_name == 'StartingRoom':
                global starting_position
                starting_position = (x, y)
            _world[(x, y)] = None if tile_name == '' else getattr(__import__('tiles'), tile_name)(x, y)

def tile_exists(x, y):
    return _world.get((x, y))
```

Comment: Can you show the full trace ?

Comment: i'm quite stupid. what do you mean?

Comment: What is printed on the console?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\fc-sr-napp-nas\Student_Home_Areas_QTree\Desktops\s45374004\pythonhere\game.py", line 24, in <module>
    play()
  File "\\fc-sr-napp-nas\Student_Home_Areas_QTree\Desktops\s45374004\pythonhere\game.py", line 5, in play
    world.load_tiles()
  File "\\fc-sr-napp-nas\Student_Home_Areas_QTree\Desktops\s45374004\pythonhere\world.py", line 22, in load_tiles
    tile_name)(x, y))
TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Comment: I think whatever this `getattr(__import__('tiles'), tile_name)(x, y)` is it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: any idea what i should put then?

Comment: _world[(x, y)] = None if tile_name == '' else getattr(__import__('tiles'), tile_name)(x, y)

Comment: `getattr(__import__('tiles'), tile_name)(x, y)` is wrong, I think. What is that calling and from where? what type of object is that returning? ie if you put `print type(getattr(__import__('tiles'), tile_name))` there, what do you get?

Comment: my guess is you want `getattr(__import__('tiles'), tile_name)[(x, y)]`

Comment: after finally fixing that stuff, thank you for helping with that, I now get (see next comment)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\fc-sr-napp-nas\Student_Home_Areas_QTree\Desktops\s45374004\pythonhere\game.py", line 24, in <module>
    play()
  File "\\fc-sr-napp-nas\Student_Home_Areas_QTree\Desktops\s45374004\pythonhere\game.py", line 5, in play
    world.load_tiles()
  File "\\fc-sr-napp-nas\Student_Home_Areas_QTree\Desktops\s45374004\pythonhere\world.py", line 20, in load_tiles
    _world[(x, y)] = (None if tile_name == '' else getattr(__import__('tiles'), tile_name)[(x, y)])
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I think you have misunderstood by comment about `print type(getattr(__import__('tiles'), tile_name))` which I was hoping you could tell me the printed output for just that line. Could you update the question with your current code?

Comment: it wont let me update it due to the "spam" and it wont let me ask another question because ive asked this question 1 day ago and I apparently need to wait 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it looks to me like you don't understand your own code very well, which is why you got downvoted. You haven't posted all the code. The key is in the function `getattr(__import__('tiles'), tile_name)(x, y)` - you're trying to pass the variables x,y to (I think) an object that isn't expecting any variables. That's what you need to understand, the correct way to use that method.

Good luck.